# React: First attempt to update component state fails

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm working on a component for my weather app and one of the features is to toggle between farenheit and celcius.  The component takes 4 properties from the parent component called `current`, `low`, `high` and `tempScale`.  The `tempScale` property serves as a boolean taking `true` or `false` values from the parent component.  `true` means the temperature should be displayed in farenheit and `false` means it should be celcius.

I load the `tempScale` property directly into a property on the component's state called `temperatureScale` and have a function called `setTemperature` that runs in the `componentDidMount` method that sets the other state properties based on its' value.  I created a function called `toggleTemperatureScale` that toggles the `temperatureScale` property and runs the `setTemperature` function.

Everything works properly, however when clicking the button to toggle between farenheit and celcius it doesn't work on the first attempt.  When `console.log()`ing the state I was even more confused, here's what's happening.

```
/*Value when component loads.  42, 50 and 35 are rendered on my screen.*/
{temperatureScale: true, currentTemperature: 0, lowTemperature: 0, highTemperature: 0}

/*Value after first click, values still the same on the screen*/
{temperatureScale: true, currentTemperature: 42, lowTemperature: 50, highTemperature: 35}

/*Value after second click, values rendered on screen are 6, 10 and 2*/
{temperatureScale: false, currentTemperature: 42, lowTemperature: 50, highTemperature: 35}

/*Value after third click, values rendered to screen are back to 42, 50 and 35*/
{temperatureScale: true, currentTemperature: 6, lowTemperature: 10, highTemperature: 2}
```

It seems like something is getting out of sync by whatever causes the first click to not work properly, here's my component.

```
export class TemperatureDisplayComponent extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            temperatureScale   : props.tempScale,
            currentTemperature : 0,
            lowTemperature     : 0,
            highTemperature    : 0
        };
        this.setTemperature         = this.setTemperature.bind(this);
        this.toggleTemperatureScale = this.toggleTemperatureScale.bind(this);
    }

    setTemperature(){
        const currentTemp = (this.state.temperatureScale === true) ? eliminateDecimals(calculateFarenheitTemperature(eliminateDecimals(this.props.current))) : eliminateDecimals(this.props.current),
              hiTemp      = (this.state.temperatureScale === true) ? eliminateDecimals(calculateFarenheitTemperature(eliminateDecimals(this.props.low))) : eliminateDecimals(this.props.low),
              lowTemp     = (this.state.temperatureScale === true) ? eliminateDecimals(calculateFarenheitTemperature(eliminateDecimals(this.props.high))) : eliminateDecimals(this.props.high);

        this.setState({ currentTemperature : currentTemp, lowTemperature : lowTemp, highTemperature : hiTemp });
        console.log(this.state);
    }

    toggleTemperatureScale(){
        this.setState(prevState =>({ temperatureScale : !prevState.temperatureScale }));
        this.setTemperature();
        //console.log(this.state);
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.setTemperature();
        console.log(this.state);
    }

    componentDidUpdate(){
        //console.log(this.state);
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <article>
                <h3>{this.state.currentTemperature}&deg;</h3>
                <h3>{this.state.lowTemperature}&deg;</h3>
                <h3>{this.state.highTemperature}&deg;</h3>
                <button onClick={this.toggleTemperatureScale}>click</button>
            </article>
        );
    }
}
```

Can anyone spot how and why that behavior is occurring?

Comment: Use async await while setting state as logging is executing before your setState method .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `setState()` does not always immediately update the component. In case you want to see the result right after the update has been applied, you should use the `setState` callback,  `(setState(updater, callback)`, like so:

```
 setTemperature(){
        const currentTemp = (this.state.temperatureScale === true) ? eliminateDecimals(calculateFarenheitTemperature(eliminateDecimals(this.props.current))) : eliminateDecimals(this.props.current),
              hiTemp      = (this.state.temperatureScale === true) ? eliminateDecimals(calculateFarenheitTemperature(eliminateDecimals(this.props.low))) : eliminateDecimals(this.props.low),
              lowTemp     = (this.state.temperatureScale === true) ? eliminateDecimals(calculateFarenheitTemperature(eliminateDecimals(this.props.high))) : eliminateDecimals(this.props.high);

        this.setState(
            { 
              currentTemperature : currentTemp, 
              lowTemperature : lowTemp, 
              highTemperature : hiTemp 
            },
            () => {
              console.log(this.state);
            }
        );           
    }
```

---

You should avoid copying props into state, like you did:

```
   this.state = {
        temperatureScale   : props.tempScale,   //Don't do this
        ...
   };
```

For reference: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor

> **Note**
>
> **Avoid copying props into state! This is a common mistake:**
>
> ```
> constructor(props) {
>  super(props);
>  // Don't do this!
>  this.state = { color: props.color };
> }
> ```
>
> The problem is that it’s both unnecessary (you can use
>   `this.props.color` directly instead), and creates bugs (updates to the
>   `color` prop won’t be reflected in the state).
>
> **Only use this pattern if you intentionally want to ignore prop**
>   **updates**. In that case, it makes sense to rename the prop to be called
>   initialColor or defaultColor. You can then force a component to
>   “reset” its internal state by [changing its
>   key](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#recommendation-fully-uncontrolled-component-with-a-key)
>   when necessary.
>
> Read our [blog post on avoiding derived
>   state](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html)
>   to learn about what to do if you think you need some state to depend
>   on the props.

Comment: thanks.  I set the `temperatureScale` property to `undefined` as default and set it to the `props.tempScale` property in the `componentDidMount` method and it works on the first click.